# Grails3, Hibernate5 - Proxy parent objects can't resolve child accessors?

Tags: hibernate, grails, hibernate-5.x, grails3

I recently upgraded my grails 3.2.10 application to hibernate5 (GORM 6.1.8) from hibernate 4 (GORM 6.1.3).  With this upgrade I've started to see some strange (incorrect?) behavior from Proxy objects, I'm wondering if I'm doing something wrong.  Here's a sample excerpt that illustrates the problem, (I realize that this isn't ideal what with the Enums, but that's what I'm working with):

Domain classes:

```
package com.test
class Socket {
  String name
  SocketType socketType //This is an enum
}

package com.test
class ElectricalOutlet extends Socket {
  Double maxOutput
  SocketType socketType = SocketType.ELECTRICAL
}
```

And service class code that uses it which is causing problems.  The implementation details are unimportant, except that `getSockets()` lazily loads a list of sockets.  Again, not ideal in this case, but this has been working under hibernate4.

```
def doSomethingWithOutlets(someKey) {
  def sockets = someOtherService.getSockets(someKey)
  sockets.each { 
    if(it.socketType == SocketType.ELETRICAL) {
      println("Class: ${it.class.name}")
      println("Output: ${it.maxOutput}")
    }
  }
}
```

The error when printing the `maxOutput` is `No such property: maxOutput for class: com.test.Socket` the class println shows `Class: com.test.Socket_$$_jvst4ae_2`.

If I add `it = GrailsHibernateUtil.unwrapIfProxy(it)` before the print statements, I get the correct `com.test.ElectricalOutlet` and `Output: blahblah` that I should.

Note also that if I try to cast the Proxy class, it fails with a `ClassCastException`

Am I missing something, or should the proxy class be able to resolve the properties of the concrete class as it has in the past?  It does not seem correct that I need to explicitly handle proxy classes throughout the code.

Comment: Did you find any solution? for work around i have used GrailsHibernateUtil.unwrapIfProxy(it).

Comment: I believe I'm using that as a workaround, but I don't recall finding an actual solution to the proxy class being unable to resolve the properties correctly...  this was a long time ago, though and I'd forgotten about it :(